# Send entire column via mail from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a column (column C) in Google Spreadsheet, I want to send via email went I put an "X" in for example cell D3.

I manage to sent an email when putting an X in D3 but I don't get the contents right, I end up receiving a different mail for each row in column C in stead of one mail containing everything from column C

Any help would be much appreciated,

EDIT: code added, very amateuristic I know, I don't know allot about this stuff..

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";  //text to put when mail has been sent

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 999;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, 3)
  //start on row 1 untill numRows
  //and 3 columns wide
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  //get content of cell A1
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    //start loop to search for data
  var row = data[i];
  var emailSent = sheet.getRange("F3").getValue(); 
  var readytosend = sheet.getRange("D3").getValue();
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && readytosend == "X") {

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "mail@mail.com",
        subject:  "test",
        body: row[0],       
        });
      //sends the email

      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      //sets email_sent value and increases i to check next row
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    }
```

Sam

Comment: Start by posting your code here please.

Comment: code added, very amateuristic I know, I don't know allot about this stuff..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you send an email for each cell. If you want to send email once, save value for each row and send at the end. Example below can do this.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";  //text to put when mail has been sent

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getMaxRows();   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C" + startRow + ":C" + numRows);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var htmlBody = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailSent = sheet.getRange("F3").getValue(); 
    var readytosend = sheet.getRange("D3").getValue();
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && readytosend == "X") {
      htmlBody += row[0] + "<br/>";
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }

  if (htmlBody && htmlBody.length) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "user@gmail.com",
        subject:  "Subject",
        body: "Email body",
        name: "Name",
        htmlBody: htmlBody
    });
  }
}
```